# Как сделать обработчик?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Мне надо сделать обработчик для выполнение запроса. 
Вот такая форма:

```
     1. Если на балансе хватает фишек, то
    вычитаем. 
     2. Если фишки вычли, то выполняем другой sql запрос.
     3. Если не хватает, то запросы не выполняются и выдаем ошибку.
```

Обработчики:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `money` = `money` - '40' WHERE `login` = '$login' AND (`money` - '40') > -1"); //Снимаем 40 фишек
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `money` = $balanceto WHERE `login` = '$login'"); //Отдаем выйгранное
```

Comment: Запрос убил...
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `money` = `money` - '40' WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `money` >= 40"); //Снимаем 40 фишек

Comment: Думаю, что здесь стОит триггер написать.

Comment: А что такое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (mysql_affected_rows()) {
// фишки сняли
}
```

Comment: А вы не могли бы написать полностью скрипт со всеми вставками скриптов? Начиная от <?php заканчивая до ?> 
p.s. Обработчики написаны выше.